# How to Use a ResourceDictionary Within a Page

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, resourcedictionary

In following http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/all-about-resourcedictionary-in-wp7 I would like to use a ResourceDictionary within my application. However I am getting an error in the xaml of my page saying `An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "/Resources/ContactListDictionary.xaml". I have created a ResourceDictionary named`ContactListDictionary.xaml`located in`Views/Resources` subfolder in the root of my application, and I am trying to add it to my page as follows

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/ContactListDictionary.xaml"/> <!-- Error -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

What am I missing? I do not have any errors within `ContactListDictionary.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">

<!-- Resource dictionary entries should be defined here. -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContactItemTemplate">
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#99FFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,10">
        <StackPanel  Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTitleXLargeStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Resources_ContactListDictionary_PhoneNumbers, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTitleMediumStyle}"/>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PhoneNumbers}" Margin="12,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,6,0" >
                            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Kind}" Margin="12, 0, 6, 0" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTitleMediumStyle}"/>-->
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMediumStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Resources_ContactListDictionary_EmailAddresses, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTitleMediumStyle}"/>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmailAddresses}" Margin="12,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,6,0">
                            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Kind}" Margin="12, 0, 6, 0" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTitleMediumStyle}"/>-->
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding EmailAddress}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMediumStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Resources_ContactListDictionary_Addresses, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTitleMediumStyle}"/>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}" Margin="12,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,6,0">
                            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Kind}" Margin="12, 0, 6, 0" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTitleMediumStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>-->
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PhysicalAddress.AddressLine1}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMediumStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PhysicalAddress.City}" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockMediumStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ContactsGroupHeaderTemplate">
    <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Padding="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ContactsGroupItemTemplate" >
    <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Padding="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ContactGroupViewTemplate">
    <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is missing `</ResourceDictionary>` close tag at the end of `ContactListDictionary.xaml`

Comment: I just accidentily left that out when copying and pasting. I had no errors within my ResourceDictionary file.

Comment: You know I created your file in my sample project and pasted your content with ending tag. Also I put the code in MainPage and it was not giving any error to me. I would suggest you to delete the file and create it again.

Comment: Ok I will try that. In mine I have my MainPage in a Views folder within the root, and my ResourceDictionary in another folder named Resources within the Views folder. I'm wondering if I am just not referencing the ResourceDictionary correctly in the MainPage.